# How to create Athena tables for dynamic S3 paths using AWS Crawler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

Below are given my S3 paths under which multiple folders are present. Each folder contains a CSV file each with a different schema.

The values within the curly braces {} will be dynamic.

```
s3://test_bucket/{val1}/data/{val2}/input/latest/

s3://test_bucket/{val1}/data/{val2}/input/archived/timestamp={val3}/
```

I want to create the Athena tables using AWS Glue Crawler. We can have a separate database for input_data both for current and archive.

The tables formed should be such that it's partitioned over **val1 and val2** both for the current and archive. And, an additional partition should be present in the table, that is, **val3**, in the case of the *archived*.

Kindly help me with any approach I can take to set the configuration for creating tables dynamically. I would really appreciate your time. Please let me know in case more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment, use the api to create the crawlers with the specific s3 paths to read, and the database name to write.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and most efficient way would be to use partition projection. Ser the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html